# How to get the count of specific days from week between a date range in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "task_table" containing columns-

Task_id, Start_date, End_date

And I have one more "configuration" table which has the records that tell which days of the week are working days.
This table has two columns -

week_day, isHoliday

and this table contains seven records as week_days are the Monday,Tuesday.....Sunday , and each record has an entry as 1 or 0. If a day is a holiday in any organization then there will be 0 against that day. Like if an organisation has holidays on Wednesday and Friday every week then there will be 0 against Wednesday and Friday only.

Now I want to make a SQL query to get the Task_id, Start_date, End_date, and the count of total days consumed on each task. (These days are the  days between task start_date and end_date excluding the holiday days as configured in "configuration" table.)

Comment: please add tables and some sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com along with the desired output for a date range from sample data to your question .

Comment: "this table contains seven records" This makes no sense to me.

Comment: I am trying to get the count of only wednesdays and fridays within a date range but I am not able to get that

Comment: seven records means for each organization "configuration" table contains seven records which are the seven days of week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to fully answer this question now, but what I would do is:

Get the date as at the start of the Start_date week, and the date as at the end of the End_date week (you can get this by `date_add`ing an amount of days according to the day of the week.

Then you want to date diff them, divide by seven, multiply by two, and remove any that you would have added (e.g. if the start date was Thursday then you'll need to remove one from the result, as you will have counted one for the Wednesday immediately prior.

I'll write the code out tomorrow (it's late here - something like 14 hours from now or so.) if noone else has suggested a better answer.

Edit: Right, didn't properly read the question, but the tactic still applies with a little fiddling. Speaking of which, [here is the fiddle of my solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d842d/1).

It boils down to the following code:

```
set @holidaysPerWeek = (select sum(isHoliday) from configuration);

select 
  Task_id,
  ((dateDiff(
    DATE_ADD(End_Date, INTERVAL 7 - DayOfWeek(End_Date) DAY),
    DATE_ADD(Start_Date, INTERVAL -DayOfWeek(Start_Date) + 1 Day)) + 1) / 7)
    * @holidaysPerWeek
    - (select sum(isHoliday) from configuration where week_day > DayOfWeek(End_Date))
    - (select sum(isHoliday) from configuration where week_day < DayOfWeek(Start_Date)),
  DayOfWeek(End_Date)
from task_table
```

This does exactly what I was saying before, but with a variable number of "weekends" spread throughout the week, by first selecting the number of holidays for if the full weeks were covered, then removing holidays that were before or after the start and end dates respectively.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. But I think think this will not work if monday is an holiday and our start date is thursday

Comment: @NikunjAggarwal Updated my answer, sorry it took a bit longer than I thought, I didn't get to do it during my lunch break.